# Which test to perform for significance testing when comparing accuracies from two models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I need to perform a test to show that accuracy results from different models are statistically significant (or not). I have been looking into https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/ but I do not know which test makes sense to perform.

I have multiple models with one accuracy score for each model. Which test should I perform for significance testing?

I have tried using the Single Sample Z Score Calculator, which gave me 3.7261 and T-Test Calculator for 2 Independent Means that returned 2769.93978, but I am not sure whether these tests are appropriate

Comment: You’re comparing two proportions, right? You know ways to do that ($\chi^2$ test, Fisher’s exact test, proportion z-test...). $\text{//}$ Why do you need to perform a hypothesis test to compare the two accuracy scores? $\text{//}$ Why use accuracy? Statisticians tend to prefer proper scoring rules like log loss.

Comment: @Dave so if I would use Chi-Sq or Fisher's exact test, then my expected loss would be 0 for the two observations since it is an optimisation task with the objective to minimize the loss?

Answer (score 0):

A z test and similar tests are not appropriate since the data are paired.  A better test would be McNemar's test, but this assumes both models predict on a single hold out set.

Even better would be to adopt a proper scoring rule and select models on that criterion.  Frank Harrell writes about this in his book Regression Modelling Strategies if I recall correctly.

Comment: seems that McNemar's test works on qualitative data only

Comment: "Accuracy" is usually the word we use to describe the proportion of instances predicted correctly when the outcome is categorical.  Is your question about regression and detecting differences in loss?

Comment: I have log loss and perplexity in my experiments